# Is it in poor form to write a paper on the same two texts that someone has already written about in a published article?

Tags: publications, etiquette, publishability

I have a proposal for a comparative literature paper that I hope to publish and/or include in some form in my dissertation. I’m discussing a wide variety of texts in my article, but the primary focus is on two novels. I’ve been planning to build upon the central thesis of one academic, but not especially well-known author’s argument in my own paper to an extent.

I later realized that this author has coincidentally published another article that focuses on the same two primary texts that I’m writing about. Although the author’s argument in this other paper is largely different from mine, and I’ll certainly cite them if any of our ideas sound similar, would it be in poor form to analyze the same two texts that this author has written about?